# Why strcpy takes const char* for src instead of char *?

Tags: c, pointers

I implemented my own strcpys to find if there is any difference between src as const char* & char *, but don't find any difference between the following 2 & both worked the same.

```
char * my_strcpy(char*dest, char* src)
{
    while ('\0' != *src)
        *dest++ = *src++;
    *dest++ = '\0';
        return dest;
}

char * my_strcpy2(char*dest, const char* src)
{
    while ('\0' != *src)
        *dest++ = *src++;
    *dest++ = '\0';
    return dest;
}
```

Is there any reason that the strcpy takes the source pointer as const char* instead of char*?

Comment: It doesn't. `strcpy` takes `const char *src` .

Comment: IMHO for historical reasons. In most cases, strcpy() can be inlined so the difference will be futile anyway.

Comment: Actually [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) have its source argument defined as `const char *restrict` since the C99 standard. See e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict) for more information about the `restrict` keyword.

Comment: Google "const correctness".

Comment: BTW The return value of your functions are strange.

Comment: To see the difference, try compiling: `my_strcpy(dest, "Hello world");`.

Comment: BTW: OP changed the question title, essentially inverting it.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any reason that the strcpy takes the source pointer as char* instead of const char*?

The source pointer should be `const char *`. The reason is common for all functions (not just `strcpy`) that do not intend to change the source accidentally inside the function.

The practice applies to both library functions like `strcpy` or your own custom functions. As with library function like `strcpy` there is no chance that the source is *accidentially* changed. But for your own (or everyone else) custom function, anything can happen. And if you do modify it *accidentially*, then you would get a compile error telling you so. And that's when the `const` is making a difference.

Answer (score 3):

"don't find any difference between the following 2" -- what could the differences be, in your wildest dreams?

The only difference the const declaration has is *on the caller side.* By the const parameter declaration the function promises not to change the memory accessed through the pointer. It promises only to read through it, which is consistent with the semantics of `strcpy()`. (Note: Whether the function *actually does not write through the pointer* is not guaranteed at all. But it promises.)

The caller can therefore call the function with a pointer to constant data and assume that the function will not attempt to write to it.

That is important syntactically, logically and materially:

- The language permits the caller to provide a pointer to const data as the argument (it would not allow that for your first non-const version).
- The caller can be sure that sensitive data is not altered inside the function as a side effect; imagine a pointer into kernel data structures here. (Counter-example: `strtok()` writes to the original string, which is therefore not declared const!)
- The data may be physically read-only (like, it may be burned into the ROM of a controller), so that an attempt to write to it would cause, well, to quote the excellent Max Barry: a ["catastrophic system failure. (...) I'm not saying it's a big deal."](http://io9.gizmodo.com/5820979/an-exclusive-excerpt-from-max-barrys-new-cyborg-novel-machine-man)

Comment: *actually does not write through the pointer is not guaranteed at all*... True, but if the programmer don't do evil (cast to remove constness), the compiler will complains.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès That is true, the implementation woud have to employ a cast or do somehting even more bogous.

Answer (score 0):

For starters function `strcpy` returns pointer to the destination string. Your function should also return pointer to the destination string. It is a common convention for functions that process strings in the C Standard.

So the function can look the following way

```
char * my_strcpy( char *dest,  const char *src )
{
    char *p = dest;

    while ( *p++ = *src++ );

    return dest;
}
```

In this case it can be called for example the following way

```
const char *hello = "Hello, World!";
char s[14];

puts( s, hello );
```

Specifying the second parameter of the function as a pointer to a constant character string means 1) that the function guarantees that it will not change the pointed string and 2) allows to pass to the function constant strings.

A pointer to a non-constant object can be implicitly converted to a pointer to constant object. The reverse operation is not allowed without explicit casting.

So if the parameter is declared like pointer to a constant string then you can pass non-constant strings along with constant strings to the same function as arguments. Otherwise the function can not be called with constant strings because the compiler will issue an error saying that it unable to convert an object of type `const char *` to an object of type `char *`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks. It was a typo as result of copy and paste.