# Why in the prototype of strcpy() function one parameter is of constant type?

Tags: c, function, prototype, strcpy

When we write the prototype of **strcpy()** function it goes like this -

char *strcpy(char *s1, const char *s2);

here the second parameter const char*s2 which is to be copied to s1 is of constant type . Why we take it as a **constant** ?

Comment: The `const` keyword is being used for documentation. It's telling you that the `strcpy` function won't change the second string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why strcpy takes const char\* for src instead of char \*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011815/why-strcpy-takes-const-char-for-src-instead-of-char)